# Day-ahead using GLM model in R

Tags: r, prediction, glm

I have the following code to get a day-ahead prediction for load consumption in 15 minute interval using outside air temperature and TOD(96 categorical variable, time of the day). When I run the code below, I get the following errors.

```
  i = 97:192
  formula = as.formula(load[i] ~ load[i-96] + oat[i])
  model = glm(formula, data = train.set, family=Gamma(link=vlog()))
```

I get the following error after the last line using glm(),

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

And the following error shows up after the last line using predict(),

```
Warning messages:
1: In if (!se.fit) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: 'newdata' had 96 rows but variable(s) found have 1 rows 
3: In predict.lm(object, newdata, se.fit, scale = residual.scale, type = ifelse(type ==  :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading
4: In if (se.fit) list(fit = predictor, se.fit = se, df = df, residual.scale = sqrt(res.var)) else predictor :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: What does `i` represent? Are you trying to fit a single model, or (192-97+1) = 96 models?

Comment: i represents number of intervals from 15 minute data.  train.set = dt.new[1:192,]
test.set = dt.new[193:288,]

Comment: So... you want to fit the model using a subset of rows from your data frame? And where does `link=vlog` come from?

Comment: Yes. But the subset in a previous day will be continuously used for a day-ahead prediction. I wrote vlog() to get rid of an error that I was getting from using gamma.

Comment: @agstudy Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Python_R You should give some data to reproduce your error. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You're doing things in a rather roundabout fashion, and one that doesn't translate well to making out-of-sample predictions. If you want to model on a subset of rows, then either subset the `data` argument directly, or use the `subset` argument.

```
train.set$load_lag <- c(rep(NA, 96), train.set$load[1:96])
mod <- glm(load ~ load_lag*TOD, data=train.set[97:192, ], ...)
```

You also need to rethink exactly what you're doing with `TOD`. If it has 96 levels, then you're fitting (at least) 96 degrees of freedom on 96 observations which won't give you a sensible outcome.

Comment: I was trying to think of a way to precisely explain how badly `formula = as.formula(load[i] ~ load[i-96]*TOD[i] + oat[i])` misunderstands how formulas work, but the best I could come up with was to point out that this results in fitting a model to a single data point.

Comment: @Hong Ooi Thank you for your help. I will try it in a bit and I will let you know if it worked for me or not.

Comment: @joran what suggestion do you have to fit the model correctly?